# CSS3 PIE - behavior HTC file doesn't load when site is accessed without trailing backslash

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, css3pie

When I access a site that uses CSS3 PIE in two different ways, the HTC file isn't found in one case. I'm using sample domain and path names to illustrate the issue below. What could be causing this to happen?

> http://sampledomain.com/site  <-- doesn't render rounded corners in
>   IE8
>
> http://sampledomain.com/site/ <-- renders rounded corners

CSS rounded corner file located at

> http://sampledomain.com/site/content/css/pie.htc

The site is including the CSS file from

> http://cdn.cdndomain.com/path/to/content/css/rounded-corners.css

The CSS:

```
.rounded-corners
{
    behavior: url(content/css/pie.htc);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite your comments elsewhere on this question, this isn't actually a bug in IE; it's handling the relative path perfectly rationally.

The reason this issue happens is because the two URLs (ie with and without the slash) are actually in different directories as far as the URL path is concerned.

- `http://sampledomain.com/site` -- this is treated as if `site` is a filename in the root directory.
- `http://sampledomain.com/site/` -- this is treated as if `site` is a directory in the root, and you're loading the default file in that directory.

So as far as the browser is concerned, the two URLs are in different directory paths. And therefore, if you specify a relative path, it will be relative to different paths in each, and one of them will clearly not point to the right place. If you have other items with relative paths, such as images, they would also have the same issue, and it will be in all browsers, not just IE. (I assume, therefore, that you don't have many other relative paths on this page)

The quick solution, as you already worked out, is to turn it into an absolute path, starting with a slash. This will ensure it's loaded from the same location in the site regardless of what the URL is that you load it from.

However, the question hints at a bigger issue. A well-behaved site should not allow both of those URLs to be valid. The URL without a slash should redirect to the URL with a slash; it should not simply load the same content regardless of whether there's a slash or not.

Allowing both URLs to load the same content is explicitly bad for your site's SEO. It means that Google will see your site as having two pages with the same content, and this in turn is counted as a minus point for your google rankings.

The issue is easy to resolve using .htaccess/mod_rewrite, and ideally, you would resolve this issue with as much urgency as the original CSS3Pie loading issue.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Spudley, this was ultimately the issue. I tried adjusting the path to an image on the page, and I was able to verify what you've described.

Comment: @ima007 - no problem. glad I was of some help :)

Answer (score 2):

Since `behavior` is a non-standard CSS property for Internet Explorer, it's implementation is also non-standard (as in, there is no spec for it). It seems like the only option is to ensure that the value for the URL in the declaration is an absolute path -- not a relative path.

This fixed the issue:

```
.rounded-corners
{
    behavior: url(/site/content/css/pie.htc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#url), a url is relative to the stylesheet - ie. in your case the cdn.  I'm not sure why it is working at all!

However, as it is working partly, I have another answer for you.  The /site url is interpreted by the browser as a page within the website - the browser has no way to tell that it is a folder without the / on the end.  That means that a relative path will be relative to the root folder of the website.  Easiest way to fix that would be to change the url to /site/content/css/pie.htc

Comment: I was actually in the process of answering my own question when you posted your answer, and thanks for confirming! And yes, the CDN url works because the behavior property in IE is relative to the source document, instead of the CSS file itself (see http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#relative-paths)

Answer (score 0):

In [standard CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url), the relative URLs are relative to the CSS document:

> The URI may be quoted by single or double quotes. Relative URIs are allowed and are relative to the URL of stylesheet (and not to the URL of the web page).

However, `behavior` is a propietary IE property and the URL is relative to the HTML file in which the sheet is being referenced, so the easier way to ensure it to work, is to use an absolute path.

If yu still want to use relative paths, you could use URL rewrite, or make copies of the `.htc` file in all possible paths, or make some other hack on the server side which makes it able to serve the `.htc` file from any path (for example in MVC you can add a route that handles all requests of `.htc` files, and use a controller that serves them from the appropriate place). As all these solutions are somewhat hacky, I prefer the absolute path, unless the app can live both in the root or in any virtual folder.